# Two insert statements or insert trigger is best?

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

I want to insert same data in two tables. What will be best - two insert statement in one sp or insert in one table and insert trigger on same table to insert data in 2nd table.

Which query will increase my performance and avoid deadlocks in table ?

Thank you in advance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggers are meant to be out of line, for cases where you must enforce things, propagate things, or when you can't handle all cases directly.

They are not meant to be a primary route for DML.

Arguably, you have a case for using a trigger, if you couldn't use a stored procedure, or if one table is meant to be "hidden" or an audit table. But if it is primary logic, you have ability to wrap it in a SP, consider whether it is good to hide the logic, out of sight is out of mind.

Avoid using triggers just to avoid writing redundant logic. That obfuscates the details.

As far as your question of performance, it amounts to the same thing. No performance advantage.

Answer (score -1):

Two inserts in one SP is on any given day better since the overhead involved in creating the trigger is uncalled for in this case.
According to MySQL Stored Procedure Programming, page 256 under the head "Trigger Overhead" says the following:

> It is important to remember that, by necessity, triggers add overhead
>   to the DML statement to which they apply. the actual amount of
>   overhead will depend upon the nature of the trigger, but --- as all
>   MySQL triggers execute FOR EACH ROW --- the overhead can rapidly
>   accumulate for statements that process large numbers of rows. You
>   should therefore avoid placing any expensive SQL statements or
>   procedural code in triggers.

An expanded explanation of trigger overhead is given on pages 529-531. The conclulding point from that section states the following:

> The lesson here is this: since the trigger code will execute once for
>   every row affected by a DML statement, the trigger can easily become
>   the most significant factor in DML performance. Code inside the
>   trigger body needs to be as lightweight as possible and -- in
>   particular -- any SQL statements in the trigger should be supported by
>   indexes whenever possible.

Comment: The question is not about MySQL, though, but about SQL Server. SQL Server simply doesn't support FOR EACH ROW triggers.